# C# Inheritance : modify base class variable from derived class

Tags: c#

I have a base class that looks as follows

```
public class base 
{
      public int x;
      public void adjust()
      {
           t = x*5;
      }
}
```

and a class deriving from it. Can I set x's value in the derived class's constructor and expect the `adjust()` function to use that value?

Comment: yea...the value is not being set. I thought I should make it some type of variable to enable that

Comment: Then show us your full code. It _should_ work, which means that there is a problem elsewhere.

Comment: well, it means that you're doing something wrong because it should work as you expect. If only you're not calling `adjust` from base class constructor. Consider posting the code you've tried.

Comment: ok. There is too much code to post. I'll see what I'm doing wrong. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, that should work entirely as expected, even though your code sample does not quite make sense (what is `t`?). Let me provide a different example

```
class Base
{
    public int x = 3;
    public int GetValue() { return x * 5; }
}
class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived()
    {
        x = 4;
    }
}
```

If we use `Base`:

```
var b = new Base();
Console.WriteLine(b.GetValue()); // prints 15
```

...and if we use `Derived`:

```
var d = new Derived();
Console.WriteLine(d.GetValue()); // prints 20
```

One thing to note though is that if `x` is used in the `Base` constructor, setting it in the `Derived` constructor will have no effect:

```
class Base
{
    public int x = 3;
    private int xAndFour;
    public Base()
    {
        xAndFour = x + 4;
    }
    public int GetValue() { return xAndFour; }
}
class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived()
    {
        x = 4;
    }
}
```

In the above code sample, `GetValue` will return `7` for both `Base` and `Derived`.

Comment: I just made up an example to explain that x is being used in the base class function :|

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it should work.

The following, *slightly modified* code will print `'Please, tell me the answer to life, the universe and everything!' 'Yeah, why not. Here you go: 42'`

```
public class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived()
    {
        x = 7;
    }
}

public class Base
{
    public int x;
    public int t;
    public void adjust()
    {
        t = x * 6;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Base a = new Derived();
        a.adjust();

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("'Please, tell me the answer to life, the universe and everything!' 'Yeah, why not. Here you go: {0}", a.t));
    }
}
```